# How to track who and when opened a document, from the document Library in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library

We have a requirement to keep a track of all the documents opened from our intranet portal? Is it possible to do it OOTB or do we have to code for it?

The portal has many sites and subsites within it, in which there are multiple document libraries. We need to track across not all site's document libraries but to specific libraries of specific site on which document was opened by which user and timestamp.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Audit Feature of SharePoint for the same:

**Configure audit settings for a site collection**

- On the site collection home page, click Site actions, point to Site settings, and then click Modify All Site Settings.
- On the Site Settings page, in the Site Collection Administration section, click Site collection audit settings.
- Select the events you want to create an audit log for, and then click OK.

**Auditing related to information management policies**

An information management policy allows users to configure audit settings for individual documents and list items based on their content type instead of the site collection settings; and auditing will be enabled for only the individual documents and list items, instead of for all items regardless of their type/business value.

Find more information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824909(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: is the same feature available in SharePoint Online?